# How do I bevel vertices in the middle of the object

Tags: bevel

[image]

Want to bevel vertices that are between two other vertices but inward, how do I do it

Comment: When you run the bevel operator, there is an option to select Vertices instead of edges. Did you try that?

Comment: Is that a flat plane or a cylinder? It should work fine whichever you are using.

Comment: What does it give when you do Ctrl B? Is it not what you want?